# sort an array based on number of set bits

Tags: c++

Example:

Input: `arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`
Output: `[0,1,2,4,8,3,5,6,7]`

Explanation: [0] is the only integer with 0 bits.
[1,2,4,8] all have 1 bit.
[3,5,6] have 2 bits.
[7] has 3 bits.
The sorted array by bits is [0,1,2,4,8,3,5,6,7]

I have tried to use custom sorting in C++ but I am not understanding where did I go wrong!

Here's my code!

```
class Solution {
public:
    static int setbits(int temp) {
        int c, n = temp;

        while(n > 0) {
            if(n & 1) c++;

            n = n >> 1;
        }

        return c;
    }

    static bool myfun(int a, int b) {
        int c1 = setbits(a);

        int c2 = setbits(b);

        if(c1 == c2 || c1 < c2) return a < b;

        return a > b;
    }

    vector<int> sortByBits(vector<int>& arr) {
        sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), myfun);

        return arr;
    }
};
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a homework solution service. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and create an [mre] demonstrating a specific issue you are having.

Comment: Note: you don't have simply copied your code as text, but with what looks like HTLM codes. It makes difficult for us to copy your code and test it.

Comment: Please paste the code as plain text in a code block in the question. You can look at the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66892024/edit) I made to see how that is done so you know how to do it the next time.

Comment: If you have C++20, take a look at [`std::popcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount)

Comment: See ravenspoint's answer - also, `c` is uninitialized in `setbits`.

Comment: See the [_strict weak ordering_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize `c` in the `setbits` function:

```
int c = 0;
```

Moreover, there was a problem in the logic of the comparator. I get correct result with

```
if (c1 == c2) return a < b;
return c1 < c2;
```

Note that the code could be more efficient by first calculating the weight of all numbers and keep them in a array.

Comment: This seems to do _strict weak ordering_ properly so +1. An easier alternative could be: `return std::tie(c1, a) < std::tie(c2, b);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you. I guess both solutions have same efficiency. Your solution is shorter, assumes a better knowledge of the library!

Comment: True. `std:.tie` helps a lot when forming long comparison functions. It can be easy to slip up and make something that doesn't fulfill the requirements of the functions in the standard library. I made a C++20 [example](https://godbolt.org/z/haaMEzfM5) for fun which follows your sort ordering (but using `tie` and `popcount`).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
   if(c1 == c2 || c1 < c2) return a < b;

    return a > b;
```

with

```
 return (c1 <= c2 );
```

Comment: This doesn't do _strict weak ordering_. If `comp(a,b)==true` then `comp(b,a)` should be `false` - but it won't be if they are equal. and `comp(a,a)` should be `false`.

Comment: Probably should be `return (c1 < c2) || (c1 == c2 && a < b);`